# After pressing the panel, its contents are not displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css

After pressing the panel, its contents are not displayed. The second and third panels are displayed at the bottom. I would like to display the content correctly after clicking on the second panel "About the website" and the third panel "Contact".

Here is the code from Codepen:
https://codepen.io/Krzysiek_39/pen/jObXzwP

Here is the code from JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Krzysiek_35/me7nytL4/198/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tab').click(function() {
    $('.tab').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });

  $('.refresh').click(function(e) {
    location.reload();
  });
});



$(function() {

  $("#tab1").addClass('one');

  $('#tab1').click(function() {
    $("#tab1").addClass('one');
    $("#tab2").removeClass('one');
    $("#tab3").removeClass('one');
  });

  $('#tab2').click(function() {
    $("#tab1").removeClass('one');
    $("#tab2").addClass('one');
    $("#tab3").removeClass('one');
  });

  $('#tab3').click(function() {
    $("#tab1").removeClass('one');
    $("#tab2").removeClass('one');
    $("#tab3").addClass('one');
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #363636;
  font-family: Verdana;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 180vh;
}

.header {
  font-family: Verdana;
  background-color: #191919;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.header .text a {
  color: #77A0AC;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.text:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-content {
  left: 5%;
  top: 10%;
  position: absolute;
}

.tablist {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.tab {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 180px;
  line-height: 35px;
  background-color: #33691e;
  color: #DDDDDD;
  font-family: Verdana;
  letter-spacing: .025em;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  margin-right: 8px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.tab:hover,
.tab:active {
  color: #DDDDDD;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #191919;
}

.tab.active {
  background-color: #191919;
}

.tab.active:before,
.tab.active:after {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.tab:last-child {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.one {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 180px;
  line-height: 35px;
  background-color: #191919;
  color: #DDDDDD;
  font-family: Verdana;
  letter-spacing: .025em;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  margin-right: 8px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.curl-top-left {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.curl-top-left:before {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, white 45%, #aaaaaa 50%, #cccccc 56%, white 80%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #363636 45%, #aaaaaa 50%, #cccccc 56%, white 80%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000');
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, height;
  transition-property: width, height;
}

.curl-top-left:hover:before,
.curl-top-left:active:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.first-curl {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.first-curl:before {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, white 45%, #aaaaaa 50%, #cccccc 56%, white 80%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #363636 45%, #aaaaaa 50%, #cccccc 56%, white 80%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000');
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, height;
  transition-property: width, height;
}

.first-curl:after {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, white 45%, #aaaaaa 50%, #cccccc 56%, white 80%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #363636 45%, #aaaaaa 50%, #cccccc 56%, white 80%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000');
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, height;
  transition-property: width, height;
}

.first-curl:hover:before,
.first-curl:active:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.first-curl:hover:after,
.first-curl:active:after,
.second-curl:hover:before,
.second-curl:active:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.second-curl {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.second-curl:before {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, white 45%, #aaaaaa 50%, #cccccc 56%, white 80%);
  background: linear-gradient(225deg, #363636 45%, #aaaaaa 50%, #cccccc 56%, white 80%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000');
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, height;
  transition-property: width, height;
}

.curl-top-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.curl-top-right:before {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, white 45%, #aaaaaa 50%, #cccccc 56%, white 80%);
  background: linear-gradient(225deg, #363636 45%, #aaaaaa 50%, #cccccc 56%, white 80%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000');
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, height;
  transition-property: width, height;
}

.curl-top-right:hover:before,
.curl-top-right:active:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.panel-1 {
  clear: both;
  width: 1000px;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: #191919;
  width: 100%;
}

.box1 .inner1 p {
  padding: 70px 30px 70px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: yellow;
}

.panel-2 {
  clear: both;
  width: 1000px;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: #191919;
  width: 100%;
}

.box2 .inner2 p {
  padding: 70px 30px 70px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: yellow;
}

.panel-3 {
  clear: both;
  width: 1000px;
}

.box3 {
  background-color: #191919;
  width: 100%;
}

.box3 .inner3 {
  padding: 1px 0px 1px;
}

.box3 .inner3 ol>li {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 0px 0px;
}

.box3 .inner3 ol>li span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 26px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div class="header">

    <div class="text">
      <a class="refresh" title="Refresh the web page">Click on me</a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="tab-content">

    <ul class="tablist" role="tablist">
      <li id="tab1" class="tab curl-top-left active" aria-controls="panel1" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">Home</li>
      <li id="tab2" class="tab first-curl second-curl" aria-controls="panel2" role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0">About the website</li>
      <li id="tab3" class="tab curl-top-right" aria-controls="panel3" role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0">Contact</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="panel1" class="panel-1" aria-labelledby="tab1" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">
      <div class="box1">
        <div class="inner1">
          <p>Home page is to be here (Slideshow)</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="panel2" class="panel-2" aria-labelledby="tab2" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="box2">
        <div class="inner2">
          <p>Here will be information about the website</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="panel3" class="panel-3" aria-labelledby="tab3" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="box3">
        <div class="inner3">

          <ol style="list-style-type: none">

            <li>
              <img src="pictures/contact/skype.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
              <span style="color: #DDDDDD; font-size: 12px">My Skype name</span>
            </li>

            <li>
              <img src="pictures/contact/gg.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
              <span style="color: #DDDDDD; font-size: 12px">Gadu-Gadu number</span>
            </li>

            <li>
              <img src="pictures/contact/mail.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
              <span style="color: #DDDDDD; font-size: 12px">My email address</span>
            </li>

          </ol>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Do you know how to make all three panels run well?

I will be very grateful for effective help.

Comment: You need to add the click listener like - $('#tab1').on('click',function(){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is not working because you are not hiding the content in your CSS or changing anything when tab is clicked.

You can add this to CSS to hide elements (except the first one) on initial load:

```
.tab-content > div
{
  display: none;
}

.tab-content[data-show-tab='1'] div:nth-of-type(1)
{
  display:block;
}

.tab-content[data-show-tab='2'] div:nth-of-type(2)
{
  display:block;
}

.tab-content[data-show-tab='3'] div:nth-of-type(3)
{
  display:block;
}
```

And add this to Javascript

```
  $("#tab1, #tab2, #tab3").on("click", function () {
        let id = jQuery(this).attr("id").replace("tab", "");
        jQuery(".tab-content").attr("data-show-tab", id);
    });
```

Change `.tab-content` tag to add `data-show-tabs` attribute to help toggling tab content:

```
<div class="tab-content" data-show-tab='1'>
```

You can also shorten your tab click handler to this one line:

```
jQuery(this).addClass("one").siblings("div").removeClass("one");
```

And this is a complete example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tab').click(function() {
    $('.tab').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });

  $('.refresh').click(function(e) {
    location.reload();
  });

});


$(function() {
  $("#tab1, #tab2, #tab3").on("click", function() {
    let id = jQuery(this).attr("id").replace("tab", "");
    jQuery(".tab-content").attr("data-show-tab", id);

    jQuery(this).addClass("one").siblings("div").removeClass("one");
  });

  $("#tab1").addClass('one');

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #363636;
  font-family: Verdana;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 180vh;
}

.header {
  font-family: Verdana;
  background-color: #191919;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.header .text a {
  color: #77A0AC;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.text:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-content {
  left: 5%;
  top: 10%;
  position: absolute;
}


/* Add this */

.tab-content>div {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content[data-show-tab='1'] div:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: block;
}

.tab-content[data-show-tab='2'] div:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
}

.tab-content[data-show-tab='3'] div:nth-of-type(3) {
  display: block;
}

.tablist {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.tab {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 180px;
  line-height: 35px;
  background-color: #33691e;
  color: #DDDDDD;
  font-family: Verdana;
  letter-spacing: .025em;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  margin-right: 8px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.tab:hover,
.tab:active {
  color: #DDDDDD;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #191919;
}

.tab.active {
  background-color: #191919;
}

.tab.active:before,
.tab.active:after {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.tab:last-child {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.one {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 180px;
  line-height: 35px;
  background-color: #191919;
  color: #DDDDDD;
  font-family: Verdana;
  letter-spacing: .025em;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  margin-right: 8px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.curl-top-left {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.curl-top-left:before {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, white 45%, #aaaaaa 50%, #cccccc 56%, white 80%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #363636 45%, #aaaaaa 50%, #cccccc 56%, white 80%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000');
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, height;
  transition-property: width, height;
}

.curl-top-left:hover:before,
.curl-top-left:active:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.first-curl {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.first-curl:before {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, white 45%, #aaaaaa 50%, #cccccc 56%, white 80%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #363636 45%, #aaaaaa 50%, #cccccc 56%, white 80%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000');
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, height;
  transition-property: width, height;
}

.first-curl:after {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, white 45%, #aaaaaa 50%, #cccccc 56%, white 80%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #363636 45%, #aaaaaa 50%, #cccccc 56%, white 80%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000');
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, height;
  transition-property: width, height;
}

.first-curl:hover:before,
.first-curl:active:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.first-curl:hover:after,
.first-curl:active:after,
.second-curl:hover:before,
.second-curl:active:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.second-curl {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.second-curl:before {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, white 45%, #aaaaaa 50%, #cccccc 56%, white 80%);
  background: linear-gradient(225deg, #363636 45%, #aaaaaa 50%, #cccccc 56%, white 80%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000');
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, height;
  transition-property: width, height;
}

.curl-top-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.curl-top-right:before {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, white 45%, #aaaaaa 50%, #cccccc 56%, white 80%);
  background: linear-gradient(225deg, #363636 45%, #aaaaaa 50%, #cccccc 56%, white 80%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000');
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, height;
  transition-property: width, height;
}

.curl-top-right:hover:before,
.curl-top-right:active:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.panel-1 {
  clear: both;
  width: 1000px;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: #191919;
  width: 100%;
}

.box1 .inner1 p {
  padding: 70px 30px 70px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: yellow;
}

.panel-2 {
  clear: both;
  width: 1000px;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: #191919;
  width: 100%;
}

.box2 .inner2 p {
  padding: 70px 30px 70px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: yellow;
}

.panel-3 {
  clear: both;
  width: 1000px;
}

.box3 {
  background-color: #191919;
  width: 100%;
}

.box3 .inner3 {
  padding: 1px 0px 1px;
}

.box3 .inner3 ol>li {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 0px 0px;
}

.box3 .inner3 ol>li span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 26px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="header">

    <div class="text">
      <a class="refresh" title="Refresh the web page">Click on me</a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="tab-content" data-show-tab='1'>

    <ul class="tablist" role="tablist">
      <li id="tab1" class="tab curl-top-left active" aria-controls="panel1" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">Home</li>
      <li id="tab2" class="tab first-curl second-curl" aria-controls="panel2" role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0">About the website</li>
      <li id="tab3" class="tab curl-top-right" aria-controls="panel3" role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0">Contact</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="panel1" class="panel-1" aria-labelledby="tab1" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">
      <div class="box1">
        <div class="inner1">
          <p>Home page is to be here (Slideshow)</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="panel2" class="panel-2" aria-labelledby="tab2" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="box2">
        <div class="inner2">
          <p>Here will be information about the website</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="panel3" class="panel-3" aria-labelledby="tab3" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="box3">
        <div class="inner3">

          <ol style="list-style-type: none">

            <li>
              <img src="pictures/contact/skype.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
              <span style="color: #DDDDDD; font-size: 12px">My Skype name</span>
            </li>

            <li>
              <img src="pictures/contact/gg.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
              <span style="color: #DDDDDD; font-size: 12px">Gadu-Gadu number</span>
            </li>

            <li>
              <img src="pictures/contact/mail.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
              <span style="color: #DDDDDD; font-size: 12px">My email address</span>
            </li>

          </ol>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: You can add that to your CSS.